# Does s3 auto scale by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does AWS S3 auto scale by default ? 
Is S3 better than using an EC2 instance, if i want to publish a website which serve mostly static content and less dynamic content.

Comment: Auto scaling is the action of automatically provisioning additional computational resources to cater user demand. EC2 instances auto-scale, however, S3 is a storage system, not a compute system, with performance best practices here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: so serving static content from s3 in not computational but same with ec2 instance is computational?

Comment: Serving static content from files in S3 is purely an I/O read operation. Serving static content from an EC2 instance means you need to provision both a general purpose CPU and an I/O controller, hence its greater expense. Under the hood, S3 of course uses RAID controllers with CPUs optimised for I/O operations, rather than general purposes CPUs used in EC2 instances for compute operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 is highly performant. You will likely never need to worry about its performance (unless you are a big user like Pinterest or Netflix).

It is certainly better to serve static content from Amazon S3 rather than an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Great answer in short, thanks, but again you left a question with your answer, what if i am a big user like Imdb or Netflix? Do they have any option which is similar to scaling but in S3 ?

Comment: If you are a big user, I would recommend you read: [Best Practices Design Patterns: Optimizing Amazon S3 Performance - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your question may be about automatically scaling s3 *storage size*.

If it's indeed the case, an Amazon s3 bucket storage size grows automatically as you add more objects into it, and there is virtually no limit on the bucket total storage capacity.

The s3 bucket will start empty and grows in storage size automatically as the number of object within the s3 bucket increase.

The only storage limit for s3 is on the individual object size. It's limited to 5Tb maximum for each object (at the time of the writing).